# Word for 'Chaotic, Erratic movement/decisions'

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title suggests, I was wondering if there is a word that fits a similar description to chaotic or erratic movement or decisions.

In one way, a word that could be inserted into this sentence 'That man can't stop ******'

Or if there's a seperate word, 'I wonder why I feel ****'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That man can't stop **[twitching](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twitch?q=twitching)**.

> Give or cause to give a short, sudden jerking or convulsive movement:

I wonder why I feel [**capricious**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/capricious#capricious).

> Given to sudden and unaccountable changes of mood or behaviour:

Answer (score 0):

> **Unpredictable**
>
> not capable of being predicted; changeable

Collins Dictionary definition.

In this case it would be 'That man cant stop being unpredictable' or better ' That man is (always/perpetually) unpredictable'

This may not be the ideal word, but it conveys a similar meaning of chaos:

> **Chaos**
>
> complete confusion and disorder : a state in which behavior and events are not controlled by anything

Merriam Webster Dictionary definition